# Ho do you stop and start php-fpm?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, magento

Ok I'm trying to install Ion Cube on an AWS instance created by Bitnami:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007OUYR4Y/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-4&qid=1413489962522

Instuctions on how to install Ion Cube for this environment can be found here:

http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP#How_in_install_IonCube_extension.3f

The problem I'm having is I have reached the restart PHP-fpm and the Apache server part but I'm receiving this error when I try to restart php-fpm. But first here is the version of php I'm running.

```
php -v
```

Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.

The following are the commands with the corresponding errors when I try to stop and/ or restart php-fpmresta:

```
$service stop php-fpm
stop: unrecognized service

$sudo service php-fpm stop
php-fpm: unrecognized service

$sudo service php5-fpm stop
php5-fpm: unrecognized service

$sudo service php5-fpm status
php5-fpm: unrecognized service

$sudo service php-fpm status
php-fpm: unrecognized service

$php-fpm restart
No command 'php-fpm' found, did you mean:

$sudo php-fpm restart
sudo: php-fpm: command not found

$service php-fpm restart
php-fpm: unrecognized service

$sudo php-fpm restart
sudo: php-fpm: command not found

$sudo service PHP-fpm stop
PHP-fpm: unrecognized service

$sudo PHP-fpm restart
sudo: PHP-fpm: command not found

$kill php-fpm
-bash: kill: php-fpm: arguments must be process or job IDs

$sudo kill php-fpm
kill: failed to parse argument: 'php-fpm'

$sudo stop php-fpm
stop: Unknown job: php-fpm

$restart php5-fpm
restart: Unknown job: php5-fpm

$sudo restart php5-fpm
restart: Unknown job: php5-fpm

$restart php4-fpm
restart: Unknown job: php4-fpm

$sudo restart php4-fpm
restart: Unknown job: php4-fpm
```

What I tried doing next was to show the process ID of php-fpm. So, I executed the following command:

```
$ sudo netstat -p
```

i got the following result in the PID/ Program name column

3590/php-fpm.conf)

I then did:

```
$ sudo kill 3590
```

typed:

```
$sudo netstat -p
```

and it showed 3690/php-fpm.conf

Are there any ideas on how to stop/ stop or restart php-fpm?

Comment: A workaround may be not to `sudo` but to run the service commands as root itself (`sudo su -`).

Answer (score 2):

I have a GitHub repo to fix it for Ubuntu - https://github.com/AbhishekGhosh/Nginx-PHP5-FPM-Restart-Fix-on-Ubuntu.

Some work needed on `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` && `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf`. All is written there. It is for Ubuntu 13, 14 etc. You possibly need a bit modification.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a really old question, but the answer is that php-fpm is not the name of your fpm service, and neither is php5-fpm. I know our system has a rather long name for this service (many words and dashes).

What you'll want to do kind of depends upon the version of your OS. If it's a systemd OS, you can use `systemctl | grep php` to try to find the service name. Hopefully the name has php in it...

If your system is an init.d OS, then you can use `initctl | grep php` to find the service name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo systemctl php5-fpm start
```

or

```
sudo systemctl php5-fpm restart
```